# How can I make a RegionPlot3D opaque with respect to the axes?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I am trying to render a hemisphere with RegionPlot3D, but I want the axes to be obscured by the plot. My current code is as follows:

```
RegionPlot3D[
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 36 && y >= 0, {x, -8, 8}, {y, -8, 8}, {z, -8, 8}, 
AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, PlotPoints -> 70, AxesStyle -> Large, 
AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, Boxed -> False]
```

But the axes show through:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One possibility it to draw the axes separately and use `Show`

I used the code to draw the axis from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16498/traditional-axes-in-3d-mathematica-plots

Now you can do,

```
axes[x_, y_, z_, f_, a_] := 
 Graphics3D[
  Join[{Arrowheads[a]}, 
   Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, #}] & /@ {{x, 0, 0}, {0, y, 0}, {0, 0, 
      z}}, {Text[
     Style["x", FontSize -> Scaled[f]], {0.9*x, 0.1*y, 0.1*z}], 
    Text[Style["y", FontSize -> Scaled[f]], {0.1 x, 0.9*y, 0.1*z}], 
    Text[Style["z", FontSize -> Scaled[f]], {0.1*x, 0.1*y, 0.9*z}]}]];

Show[RegionPlot3D[
  x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 36 && y >= 0, {x, -8, 8}, {y, -8, 8}, {z, -8, 8},
  AxesLabel -> {x, y, z},
  PlotPoints -> 70,
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
  Axes -> False, (* make sure to turn this off here*)
  Boxed -> False],
 axes[10, 10, 10, 0.05, 0.02], (*this draws axis manually*)
 PlotRange -> All
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 8):

Draw and tailor axes separately (under different names if needed).

```
axesOnly=Graphics3D[{
        Black , Arrowheads[0.02]
  
   , Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {10, 0, 0}},.05]]
   , Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {-10, 0, 0}},.05]]
   , Text[Style["x", Italic, Bold, 14], {11, 0, 0}]
   
   , Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 10, 0}}, .05]]
   , Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, -10, 0}}, .05]]
   , Text[Style["y", Italic, Bold, 14], {0, 11, 0}]
   
   , Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 10}},.05]]
   , Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -10}}, .05]]
   , Text[Style["z", Italic, Bold, 14], {0, 0, 11}]
  
   }
  (**)
  ]
```

[image]

Use opacity and block axes and box frame.

```
Show[
 RegionPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 36 && y >= 0
  , {x, -12, 12}, {y, -12, 12}, {z, -12, 12}
  , PlotPoints -> 70
  , PlotStyle -> {Opacity[1]}
  , AxesEdge -> {None, None, None}
  , Boxed -> False
 (*, Lighting -> {White, "Ambient"}*)
 ,ImageSize->600
  ],
 axesOnly
 ]
```

[image]